# Redirecting to a page from authentication flow in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My application has to authenticate the user with an external OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow. I am using ReactJS as the framework for this website.
The way I do it is shown here:

First, in the main page there is a check if the access token is there. If it is not there, it redirects the user to the login component where it will start the authorization code flow.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./css/App.css";
import Redirect from "./Components/Redirect";
import Login from "./Components/Login";

import axios from "axios"

function App() {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
  const [tokenExpirationDate] = useState(localStorage.getItem('tokenExpiration'))

  const getToken = (token) => {
    setAccessToken(token);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let currentTime = Date.now()
    if(tokenExpirationDate < currentTime) {
      setAccessToken(null)
    }
  }, [])


  if(accessToken)
  {
    return (
          <Router>
            <div className="apps">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/dashboard">
                  //Other components
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router >   
    )
  } else
  {
    return (
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                  <Login />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/redirect">
                  <Redirect
                      sendToken = {getToken}
                  />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router >

    );
  }
} 

export default App
```

The Login component just shows a button for the user to send to the authentication page of the resource we need it to authenticate with.

```js
import React from 'react'
import "../css/Login.css"

const Login = () => {

    return (
        <div className="loginScreen">
            <h1>You are currently not logged in!</h1>
            <h2>Click
                <a href="https://{url}/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&scope={scopes}l&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/redirect"> HERE </a>
                to log in
            </h2>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Once the user has gone through this login page, it is redirected to the Redirect component. In here the access token is pulled from the response and put in the localstorage (I know, not secure but this is mainly for testing) and sent through the properties to be set in the main page. The user is then supposed to be sent back to the dashboard using the useHistory hook. However, when this happens the page is turned blank. The URL is correct, but the page does not load at all. Refreshing the page does send the user to the dashboard like it is intended to do.

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import oauth from "axios-oauth-client";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const Redirect = props => {
    const history = useHistory()

    const code = window.location.href.split("=")[1]

    const getInfo = () => {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const getAuthorizationCode = oauth.client(axios.create({
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }), {
                    url: url,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    client_id: clientId,
                    client_secret: clientSecret,
                    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect',
                    code: code,
                })

                await getAuthorizationCode().then(function(response) {
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token)
                    const expirationDate = Date.now() + (response.expires_in * 1000)
                    localStorage.setItem('tokenExpiration', expirationDate)
                    props.sendToken(response.access_token);
                    history.push("/dashboard")
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }

    getInfo()

    return (
        <h1>Retrieving access token</h1>
    );
}

export default Redirect
```

So in short, the authentication flow should send the user to the dashboard automatically however it remains blank. I think this is because the useHistory hook only works if the page has been loaded before and the dashboard page has not been loaded yet, but I really cannot find a way to make this work. The console does not show any errors either.

I'm really stuck here, and I cannot find anything online. Is anyone able to help?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is caused by having two different Routers... try to wrap whole condition in your `App.tsx` into one Router instead.

Comment: No problem, then mark this please as correct answer :)